# I want to change a variable to have no newline similar to what end='' does in print

Tags: python, for-loop

Example Code:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3]
for i in list1:
     if i == 123:
           print('E')
     else:
           pass
```

Here I want to make the variable of i = 123 and not

i =

1

2

3

Basically remove newlines

I know of the end='' used in print statements is there something like that, that can change the variable itself?

Comment: There are no newlines in the variable itself; the variable is an int value, it couldn't have a newline in it if it wanted to.  `print` adds a newline by default, which is why you have to say `end=''` to not do that.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense: you have a list of three integers, `i` will never equal `123` because that value isn't in the list.

Comment: You're literally looping over a list that contains a `1`, a `2` and a `3`, so there's no surprise that `i` will take those values one at a time, and if you were to print them (which you don't do), you'd see them on separate lines. Are you asking how to combine a list with separate digits like `[1, 2, 3]` into a single number like `123`? Note that there's a big difference between values of variables like `1` or `123` and their string representations like `'1'` or `'123'`.

Comment: Im sorry im new to python

Comment: That's OK - basic questions are valid questions, but we need to understand your problem well enough to provide an answer that actually helps you. Are you only asking how to print the contents of a list of integers like `[1, 2, 3]` to the screen without spaces or line endings? Or are you asking how to combine such a list of numbers into a larger number value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to concatenate the list, this returns '123' as an integer:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]

var = [str(i) for i in list1]
new_var = ''.join(var)

num = int(new_var)

print(num)
```

Comment: You shouldn’t use variable names like `str` that are defined as a type; this will redefine the definition.

Comment: if it is really needed to just convert list of integers to single integer, better use `reduce(lambda x,y : x * 10 + y , list1)`  as you dont have to go back-and-forth with type casting.  P.S. reduce is in `functools`

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you want to *concatenate* a list of digits into a single *integer*:

```
int(''.join([str(d) for d in list1]))
```

Taking it apart:

1. `[str(d) for d in list1]` convert all digits to their string representation
2. `''.join(<list of strings>)` concatenate list of strings into a single string (no spaces)
3. `int(<string of digits>)` convert a string of digits to an int

Comment: I have a question what is the difference between [str(d) for d in list1] and for d in list1?

Comment: `[str(d) for d in list1]` is a *list comprehension* that will return a (new) list, replacing each digit by it's string-equivalent. `for d in list1` is a simple for-loop, that will iterate over each digit (in their original format) contained in `list1`.